# node-gyp configure build error

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

I'm trying to compile a 3rd party code to add on to the node. I have node: 0.10.12, node-gyp: 0.10.6; I installed a binary version of node instead of compiling.

When running "node-gyp configure build" I got a time out error because I am behind a firewall and use a proxy server:

```
node-gyp  configure build  
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok  
gyp info using node-gyp@0.10.6  
gyp info using node@0.10.12 | linux | x64  
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.12/node-v0.10.12.tar.gz  
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install  
gyp ERR! configure error  
gyp ERR! stack Error: connect ETIMEDOUT  
gyp ERR! stack     at errnoException (net.js:901:11)  
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)  
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64  
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "configure" "build"  
gyp ERR! cwd /root/software/WebFM/tvanode-master  
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.12  
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.6  
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Why does it try to retrieve the same version of node from nodejs.org instead of using the local one I have?

When tried with "node-gyp configure build --proxy=http://myproxy.com" I got an incorrect error:

```
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok  
gyp info using node-gyp@0.10.6  
gyp info using node@0.10.12 | linux | x64  
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.12/node-v0.10.12.tar.gz  
gyp http 200 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.12/node-v0.10.12.tar.gz  
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install  
gyp ERR! configure error  
gyp ERR! stack Error: incorrect header check  
gyp ERR! stack     at Zlib._binding.onerror (zlib.js:295:17)  
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64  
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "--proxy=http://myproxy.com/" "configure" "build"  
gyp ERR! cwd /root/software/WebFM/tvanode-master  
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.12  
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.6  
gyp ERR! not ok
```

I compiled and installed node.js 0.10.15; and tried downgrading it to 0.8.15 but got the same error.

Comment: can you try running as root?

Comment: @vinayr I was running as root.

Comment: I had it working on my PC:      
gyp info using node-gyp@0.9.3    
gyp info using node@0.8.15 | win32 | ia32    
gyp info spawn C:\Python27\python.exe    

But the Linux one is still not working. Why is it trying to download a node when I have it locally?   gyp info using node-gyp@0.9.3    
gyp info using node@0.8.15 | linux | x64    
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.15/node-v0.8.15.tar.gz    
gyp http 200 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.15/node-v0.8.15.tar.gz    
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install    
gyp ERR! configure error  
gyp ERR! stack Error: incorrect header check

Comment: Regardless of what version of node is actually installed on your system `node-gyp` downloads the necessary development files for the target version. You can find that in `~/.node-gyp/`. Guess you are behind firewall, but then `--proxy` should solve the problem. See if you can access http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.15/node-v0.8.15.tar.gz from your browser or `wget`.

Comment: Yes, I am behind a firewall. From the response I believe I can access nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.15/node-v0.8.15.tar.gz:               gyp http 200 nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.15/node-v0.8.15.tar.gz         gyp WARN install got an error.

Comment: @vinayr I misinterpreted the return code. Though it returned 200 (OK) the download was blocked by the proxy. Now it works.